# Suppose $P$ and $Q$ are orthogonal projections and $P+Q = I$. Prove that $P-Q$ must be an orthogonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, projection, orthogonal-matrices

By theorem of orthogonal projections we have $P^T=P=P^2$ and $Q^T=Q=Q^2$. By definition we need to show that $(P-Q)^T(P-Q) = I = (P-Q)(P-Q)^T$. Note that $P+Q = I \iff P = I - Q$. Observe
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        (P-Q)^T(P-Q) &= (P^T-Q^T)(P-Q) \\
        &= P^TP - P^TQ - Q^TP + Q^2 \\
        &= P - PQ - QP + Q \\
        &= (I-Q) - (Q-Q^2) - (Q-Q^2) + Q\\
        &= I.
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
And
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        (P-Q)(P-Q)^T &= (P-Q)(P^T-Q^T) \\
        &= PP^T -PQ^T -QP^T + QQ^T  \\
        &= P^2 - PQ - QP + Q^2 \\
        &= P - PQ-QP - Q \\
        &= (I-Q) - (I-Q)Q-Q(I-Q)+Q \\
        &= I-Q +Q \\
        &= I.
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Hence $P-Q$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Is this a valid prove? Have I made correct use of the carrying out of the transposes?

Comment: This looks right to me. Note however that you only need to go one way, since for square matrices if $AB = I$ then $BA = I$ automatically. Also, I think the "key insight" here is that if $P, Q$ are projections with $P + Q = I$, then $PQ = 0 = QP$. We then get $(P - Q)^2 = P^2 - QP - PQ + Q^2 = P + Q = I$, which is more or less what this boils down to checking once you throw the transposes away.

Comment: Oh yes. I see now. Easily showing that $(P-Q)^T = P-Q$ then I can do the easy $(P-Q)^2$ calculation to make it much shorter.